# Openstack nova-compute service is not recognized as compute service in controller node (probably rabbitmq connection problem)

Tags: rabbitmq, timeout, openstack, openstack-nova

I was following the tutorials on Openstack docs website for a minimal deployment of the Stein release (I am installing it on Ubuntu 18.04 instances). I installed the nova services and made the required configuration. Then I reached [this stage](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/stein/install/compute-install-ubuntu.html#add-the-compute-node-to-the-cell-database) and ran the following command on the controller node.

```
openstack compute service list --service nova-compute
```

I was expecting to see a nova-compute service running on a compute host as the result, but I get nothing.
I looked at the `nova-compute.log` file on my comupte node (`/var/log/nova/nova-compute`)
and I have this error:

```
.
.
.
2022-04-25 06:33:46.682 4015 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-313f4c65-0f63-4d8b-8682-6295770701af - - - - -] Connection failed: timed out (retrying in 32.0 seconds): socket.timeout: timed out
2022-04-25 06:34:23.745 4015 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-313f4c65-0f63-4d8b-8682-6295770701af - - - - -] Connection failed: timed out (retrying in 32.0 seconds): socket.timeout: timed out
2022-04-25 06:35:00.803 4015 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-313f4c65-0f63-4d8b-8682-6295770701af - - - - -] Connection failed: timed out (retrying in 32.0 seconds): socket.timeout: timed out
2022-04-25 06:35:37.860 4015 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-313f4c65-0f63-4d8b-8682-6295770701af - - - - -] Connection failed: timed out (retrying in 32.0 seconds): socket.timeout: timed out
2022-04-25 06:36:14.920 4015 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-313f4c65-0f63-4d8b-8682-6295770701af - - - - -] Connection failed: timed out (retrying in 32.0 seconds): socket.timeout: timed out
.
.
.
```

Apparently, it has a problem connecting to the rabbitmq service. I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything of use in my case. I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. I'd be very happy if someone could give me an answer.

Comment: First, check `rabbitmq` status and listening port. Then verify that whether the `rabbitmq`'s port works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Victor Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6240879/victor-lee) suggested in the comments, I checked `rabbitmq`'s port and nothing was wrong there. It was running with no problem. Turned out my firewall didn't allow incoming traffic through `rabbitmq`'s port. So I added a rule to allow it.